# How to run a long process/function on button click django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, web

Im trying to do a django website in which:

1. I take a user input from the template (done)
2. Save the input in the view (done)
3. On a button click, user starts a function that send a api request every x seconds and if the function find a different api response then show it in template as status.

And i have no idea how to achieve the 3rd point. This is how the api request function looks like:

```
def function(zapytaniex,fraza,kategoria): 
    starttime = time.time()
    data1 = zapytaniex
    while True:
        data2 = apirequest(fraza = fraza, categoryid = kategoria)
        if data1 != data2:
            context["status"] = "got new offer"
                                
        elif data1 == data2:
            context["status"] = "still nothing"

        time.sleep(120.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 120.0))
```

As you can see this function send the api request every 2 minutes and I want to run this function when user clicks a button and then update a status context in a template WITHOUT refreshing the whole page.
I tried to run it with threading but the page keep loading when the thread in working.

Thanks for any help and ideas!

Comment: How are you sending requests from client? Do you use AJAX requests?

Comment: Firstly, it was just a program on my computer and then i thought to make a website from it, so the requests are simple python post requests on api url.